# devtoolset-10,undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, centos7, devtoolset

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/YikeSim.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/data/mpich/bin/mpic++   -Wl,--rpath=./shared_lib/linux -std=c++17 -g -O3 -mavx -fopenmp -Wall -D CMAKE_COMPILE -L /usr/lib64      CMakeFiles/YikeSim.dir/src/main/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/YikeSim.dir/src/yikesim/extern/NanoLog.cpp.o  -o out/build/mingw-build/YikeSim  -L/data/project/YikeFDTDBook/YikeSim/shared_lib/linux  -L/data/project/YikeFDTDBook/YikeSim/static_lib/linux -rdynamic -lboost_timer -lboost_chrono -lboost_thread -lpython3.8 -lc -lopenblas -lgmsh -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,/data/project/YikeFDTDBook/YikeSim/shared_lib/linux:/data/project/YikeFDTDBook/YikeSim/static_lib/linux 
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/ld: CMakeFiles/YikeSim.dir/src/main/main.cpp.o: in function `std::string::_M_check(unsigned long, char const*) const':
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:3392: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/ld: /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:3392: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)'
```

This is the message I get when I compile the program with an error. I have searched the web for a solution and most of the answers are about the `GCC` version. But I have tried `devtoolset-8`, `devtoolset-9`, `devtoolset-10` and still get the same error. I hope there is an effective solution to this problem, thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't post code or error messages as images. Instead copy-paste as text.

Comment: Possible duplicate [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: This looks like a mismatch between your compiler and the libstdc++ used for linking which is probably the old and default one on your system.

Does your LD_LIBRARY_PATH include the path to the appropriate libstdc++ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.